# Получение выбранного значения из ComboBox, расположенного в DataGrid WPF C#

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid, combobox

Всем привет! Подскажите, пожалуйста, не могу достать значение из Combobox, который расположен в DataGrid. 
Пример XAML:

```
 <DataGrid Margin="10,19,10,10" AutoGenerateColumns="False" Grid.Row="1" Name="dgPipePlast" 
                      ItemsSource="{Binding Source={x:Static local:MainWindow.SystemForPlastPipe}}"  CanUserAddRows="False"
                      >
                <DataGrid.Columns>
                    <DataGridTextColumn Header="Имя системы" IsReadOnly="True" Width="80" Binding="{Binding System}"/>
                    <DataGridTextColumn Header="Диаметр" IsReadOnly="True" Width="60" Binding="{Binding Diameter}" />
                    <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Марка" Width="Auto">
                        <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding MaterialPlast}" Name="cbdg"
                                          SelectedValue="{Binding SteelGrade}"
                                          SelectedItem="{Binding SteelGrade}"></ComboBox>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    </DataGridTemplateColumn>
                    <DataGridTextColumn Header="ГОСТ" IsReadOnly="True" Width="Auto" Binding="{Binding Gost}"/>
                </DataGrid.Columns>
            </DataGrid>
```

В коде

```
//Работа с таблицец по маркам пластиковых труб
        System.Collections.IEnumerable col_plastpipe = dgPipePlast.Items.SourceCollection;
        var lsttableplastpipe = new List<ElementData>();


        foreach (TablParameter i in col_plastpipe)
        {
            lsttableplastpipe.Add(new ElementData { Systems = i.System, Diameter = i.Diameter, SteelGrade = i.SteelGrade });

            Parameters.SetLstTablPipePlast(lsttableplastpipe);
        }
        ;
```

При отработке программы получается, что значение SteelGrade = null.

Comment: Вот в XAML у вас все прям почти идеально, привязки есть, все хорошо и более менее красиво (кроме `x:Static` привязки, зачем?). Но код... Зачем вы делаете `dgPipePlast.Items.SourceCollection`, если у вас уже есть привязанная коллекция `MainWindow.SystemForPlastPipe`? В чем смысл коллекции `lsttableplastpipe` (да и вообще всего приложенного кода)? А, ну и где ваши `SteelGrade` свойства? Кстати вы делаете привязку `SelectedValue` и `SelectedItem` к одному свойству, когда их тип совершенно разный. В общем мне совершенно не понятен ваш подход и то, что вы тут делаете. Начали хорошо, а дальше...

Comment: Спасибо за отзыв. Я еще новичок, отсюда такие нелепые ошибки.
Изначально я строю DataGrid,  в котором есть столбец с Combobox, который подставляется в зависимости от значений диаметра трубы и типа системы (это уже реализовал)
Затем в появившимся окне пользователь выбирает значение из Combobox. После нажатия кнопки ОК,  я должен наполнить "lsttableplastpipe" экземплярами класса, в свойстве класса которого должен выводиться выбранное значение

Comment: А, ну и где ваши SteelGrade свойства?
- Они в классе TablParameter. Может я ошибаюсь, но я хочу выбранное из Combobox значение присвоить к свойству экземпляра класса

Кстати вы делаете привязку SelectedValue и SelectedItem к одному свойству, когда их тип совершенно разный.
- Согласен, конечно, я просто по разному пробовали ничего не вышло

 (кроме x:Static...) 
- Спасибо за замечание, исправил!

Comment: Сделайте грамотную привязку, уберите все `Name` в XAML (не работайте с контролами через код) и тогда вам станет в разы проще эту задачу решить, ибо многое на себя возьмет сама привязка.